# Why are statements being processed in the wrong order in a function containing SQLite commands?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite (and relatively new to programming in general) so sorry if the answer is obvious. Does anyone know why when I run the following function, the alert at the end is displayed before the alert inside the database transaction?

The "inside transaction" alert shows that the variable "recipeRating" holds the appropriate number (10 in this case), but the "outside transaction" alert shows that it holds zero. All I want is for the "recipeRating" variable to hold the correct value at the end of the function so it can be returned and used elsewhere. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this and/or why the alerts appear in the wrong order?

```
function calculateRecipeRating(newRecipeName,newIngredient1,newIngredient2,newIngredient3){

var recipeRating = 0;

db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Ingredients', [], function(transaction, result) {
        if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = result.rows.item(i);

                var ingRating = parseInt(row.IngredientRating);

                if(row.IngredientName == newIngredient1 || row.IngredientName == newIngredient2 || row.IngredientName == newIngredient3){

                    recipeRating = recipeRating + ingRating

                }

            }
        }

        alert("inside transaction = " + recipeRating);

    },errorHandler);
},errorHandler,nullHandler);

alert("after transaction = " + recipeRating);

}
```

Comment: The function is async, everything inside the callback functions will execute once the operations are complete. Everything outside will keep functioning without it

Comment: I see, thank you for the info. Is there any easy way around my problem  then or does this require re-thinking completely?

Comment: Just do what ya need to do with the information inside the callbacks, why put it outside the function